# How to display output of a python program in a text box in asp.net Web Form?

Tags: python, c#, asp.net

I was create hellow.py script as bellow

```
print('Hello, world!')
```

I tried like this.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var proc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "c:/python38/python.exe",
            Arguments = "hellow.py",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };

    proc.Start();
    while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        // do something with line
        TextBox1.Text = line;
    }

}
```

But string line is null every time.  I changed  FileName = "c:/python38/python.exe" as different types :

1. "c:\python38\python.exe" - error says unrecognized escape sequence
2. @"c:\python38\python.exe" - no error, but line = null
3. "c:/python38/python.exe" - no error, but line = null
4. "c:\python38\python.exe" - no error, but line = null?

Whatever the reason?

Comment: How are you going to deploy this. an IIS server would not be able to do this unless configured.. aside that, Q: are you sure your Python *can find* hellow.py ? Error messages could go to standard error, so you wont see them. Did you test a fully qualified path for hellow.py ? With the directory name included ?

Comment: Thanks Goodies. After I change the py.py file path with full local file path. that's work thank you very much.

Comment: It was just a suggestion.. but apparently it's the answer here, I'll put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Python can't find hellow.py

Use a fully qualified name for hellow.py

That is include a directory name, e.g. c:\MySources\ok\hellow.py

Comment: Thanks Goodies. After I change the py.py file path with full local file path. that's work thank you very much.